# How to get axios error response while testing in nestjs without timing out

Tags: nestjs

The following code works (it gets the latest video uploaded to a youtube playlist via a playlistID), but I'm trying to change it so that it passes the error response if a bad playlistID is supplied.

get_latest_upload.service.spec.ts

```js
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { GetLatestUploadService } from './get_latest_upload.service';
import { HttpService } from '@nestjs/axios';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { createMock, DeepMocked } from '@golevelup/ts-jest';

describe('GetLatestUploadService', () => {
  let service: GetLatestUploadService;
  let httpService: jest.Mocked<HttpService>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [],
      providers: [
        { provide: HttpService, useValue: createMock<HttpService>() },
        ConfigService
      ],
      controllers: [
        GetLatestUploadService
      ],
    }).compile();

    service = module.get<GetLatestUploadService>(GetLatestUploadService);
    httpService = module.get(HttpService);
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined();
  });

  describe('getLatestUpload(id)', () => {
    it('sholud return youtube video id', async () => {
      const playlistID = "PLcGkkXtask_eafKUbnGPBuCsLt2LN8SQe";
      const testData = require(`../../test/playlists/${playlistID}.json`);
      const testID = testData.items[0].snippet.playlistId;
      const videoID = testData.items[0].snippet.resourceId.videoId;
      httpService.axiosRef.mockResolvedValueOnce({
        data: testData,
        headers: {},
        config: { url: '' },
        status: 200,
        statusText: '',
      });
      const getLatestUpload = service.getLatestUpload(testID);
      await expect(getLatestUpload).resolves.toBe(videoID);
    });
  });
});
```

get_latest_upload.service.ts

```js
import { Inject, Injectable, Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { HttpService } from '@nestjs/axios';
import { firstValueFrom, catchError } from 'rxjs';
import { AxiosError } from 'axios';
import { AxiosResponse } from 'axios';

@Injectable()
export class GetLatestUploadService {
  @Inject(ConfigService)
  public config: ConfigService;
  private readonly logger = new Logger(GetLatestUploadService.name);
  constructor(private readonly httpService: HttpService) {}

  async getLatestUpload(playlistID): Promise<string> {
    const apiKey: string = this.config.get('YOUTUBE_API_KEY');
    const part = "snippet%2C+id";  
    const url = `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=${part}&playlistId=${playlistID}&key=${apiKey}&order=date&maxResults=1`;
    const { data } = await this.httpService.axiosRef({
      url: url,
      method: `GET`,
    });    
    const videoId = data.items[0].snippet.resourceId.videoId;
    return videoId;
  }
}
```

If a bad playlistID was supplied, the error response from youtube-api would look like:

```js
{
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
      "message": "The playlist identified with the request's <code>playlistId</code> parameter cannot be found.",
      "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The playlist identified with the request's <code>playlistId</code> parameter cannot be found.",
        "domain": "youtube.playlistItem",
        "reason": "playlistNotFound",
        "location": "playlistId",
        "locationType": "parameter"
      }
      ]
  }
}
```

This is accomplished by changing the `const { data }` in `get_latest_upload.service.ts` from

```js
const { data } = await this.httpService.axiosRef({
  url: url,
  method: `GET`,
});
```

to

```js
const { data } = await firstValueFrom(
  this.httpService.get(url).pipe(
    catchError((error: AxiosError) => {
      this.logger.error(error.response.data);
      throw 'An error happened!';
    }),
  ),
);
```

but this causes the `get_latest_upload.service.spec.ts` to fail with

```
thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a test.
```

when calling `await expect(getLatestUpload).resolves.toBe(videoID);`

So when using httpService.axiosRef to query youtube-api, the test file works.
But when using httpService.get to query youtube-api, the test file times out.

My goal is to catch the error response as in my example of using httpService.get, but I've not found a way to do this properly that works with my test file.

Answer (score 1):

[Handling Errors With Axios](https://axios-http.com/docs/handling_errors)

```js
axios.get('/user/12345')
  .catch(function (error) {
    if (error.response) {
      // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
      // that falls out of the range of 2xx
      console.log(error.response.data);
      console.log(error.response.status);
      console.log(error.response.headers);
    } else if (error.request) {
      // The request was made but no response was received
      // `error.request` is an instance of XMLHttpRequest in the browser and an instance of
      // http.ClientRequest in node.js
      console.log(error.request);
    } else {
      // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
      console.log('Error', error.message);
    }
    console.log(error.config);
  });
```

Comment: I believe this is somewhat the way I catch the error in my above code, the problem doing it this way is causing my test file to timeout.  I'm trying to catch the error without timing out my test file.